# Being told to monitor a frequency, when are you allowed to transmit on that frequency?

Tags: air-traffic-control

Changing frequency, how long do you have to wait before you are allowed to transmit if you have been told to monitor the frequency. Is there a specific time limit? In what aviation manual can the answer be found?

Comment: I'm often told this *"taxi to parking, monitor ground point-9"* after landing. It doesn't mean I *can't* talk to ground, it just means I don't *have* to, since I already have my clearance. If I need something from ground I can contact them immediately, there is no requirement to wait.

Answer (score 13):

First a note on phraseology. In the context of your question, I believe the FAA uses *monitor* like most of the world uses *stand by*. I'll be covering the general procedure - if you are in FAA land, replace *stand by* in my answer with *monitor*.

If told to monitor a frequency, you are not expected to transmit on that frequency. Monitor is used when a pilot is requested to listen on a frequency to retrieve information from a broadacst. For example, I might tell you to *Monitor ATIS 122.750*. I then expect you to tune 122.750, listen to the ATIS transmission, and then return back to my frequency afterwards.

If told to stand by on a frequency, you are expected to tune that frequency and wait for air traffic control to contact you there. For example, *Standby for Tower on 118.1*. When standing by on a frequency, air traffic control is supposed to contact you, not the other way around. However, if you do not get contacted within a reasonable amount of time, you should go ahead and transmit. There is no fixed rule for how long you have to wait - use common sense - just like you would if told to stand by on your current frequency. For example, if you are waiting in line for departure and there are 3 aircraft ahead of you, don't expect the tower to call you before you are next in line for departure. On the other hand, if you are holding short of the runway and there appears to be no other traffic around preventing you from taking off, if the tower hasn't called you within a minute or so, please do try to call them instead. Maybe the controller is busy dealing with other stuff, or maybe they have simply forgotten about you. It does happen, although not often. You could also accidentally have tuned the wrong frequency, and might only realise this when no one replies to a call made by you. It goes without saying that, if you have a safety related message, you transmit it without delay.

Comment: I've never heard a controller in the US say "monitor" when they mean "stand by". I don't believe the US uses it in that context anywhere, it would be confusing.

Comment: @ronbeyer What I meant was, US controllers use "Monitor tower 118.1" instead of "Standby for tower on 118.1". I am fully aware that they don't use "Monitor" with the meaning "Wait, I will call you back." Answwer edited to clarify.

Comment: I understood the meaning, I've never heard it that way. I've never been told to transfer to a frequency and "wait to be contacted", it is always "contact Tower on 118.1" and I change frequencies and say "XYZ tower, N12345 Inbound to land two-four", tower will then respond or say "12345 stand by"

Comment: @ronbeyer It does certainly exist in the US as well. Took me 5 seconds to find this on Google: https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ATC.pdf. Searching for "monitor" in that document proves it.

Comment: [FAA Pilot/Controller Glossary](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/pcg_change2.pdf) MONITOR− (When used with communication transfer) listen on a specific frequency and stand by for instructions. Under normal circumstances do not establish communications.

Comment: "When used _with communication transfer_" - Key takeaway from that would be when "monitor" is used *with a transfer* of communications. Telling you to monitor a channel and wait for instructions isn't a positive transfer. I agree with Ron here. I know the term "monitor" does exist in US airman lexicon, but I don't think it means what's implied here. "Monitor" is for actively listening to a frequency. Even the documents posted seem to support that. .....

Comment: ... It doesn't come across as an instruction to change freq and wait to be contacted. And if a controller issued a "monitor" without a "contact" instruction, I'd be asking for clarification. That's not standard phraseology. Regardless, you shouldn't leave a frequency without a positive transfer. "Monitor" doesn't accomplish that.

Comment: I guess I just don't see an instruction to go to a channel and wait for the controller to contact you as being a realistic situation. Even in a busy airport, I will be told to "Contact x", and if they are very busy and can't immediately acknowledge, they should get back to me within 5 minutes. If they don't, I should contact them again. My initial contact lets that controller know I am there and about to be in his/her control space.

Comment: And to answer the original question..... JO 7110.65W, which was the ATC doc previously posted, 2-1-17.b."NOTE−
For the purposes of this paragraph, a reasonable amount
of time is considered to be 5 minutes from the time the
aircraft enters the controller’s area of jurisdiction or comes
within range of radio/communications coverage..."

Comment: Very good comments, thank you. Shawn, is it possible to post a link to the document in question?

Comment: @Shawn I might be misunderstanding your comments, but flying in the US, particularly at busier airports, it is very common for me to be told by ground something like "N123XY, monitor tower, good day." and they certainly do mean to switch to the tower frequency and wait for *them to call you*, and not the other way around.  It also happens when clearance says to monitor ground for taxi. It helps with frequency congestion since you calling them only to hear "standby" (over and over for each airplane) would add two unnecessary transmissions.

Comment: @Lnafziger I haven't been flying for many years, so I don't know if SOPs have changed, but I doubt they would have. I have been told to monitor a frequency, but never with the expectation to change the channel and wait for a call to me. If it was for an active contact or a transfer, I was always instructed to "contact x". Or at least always expected to switch the channel and simply announce my presence. Otherwise, how would the controller know I made it there? If they were busy, they'd get to me when they could.

Comment: @Shawn Well, if they told you to "contact x" as you say, then you **are** expected to contact them.  If told to "monitor x" then you should do just that: switch to the frequency and monitor it.  They have internal procedures so that they know who has been instructed to monitor the frequency, and as a pilot, it will be obvious if you misdial a frequency because you won't hear any transmissions to/from other aircraft.  As I said, it's typically done at very busy airports and they pass the strips between different stations so that they know who is waiting.

Comment: @Lnafziger I stand corrected. I spoke with my dad, who has been a FedEx pilot since 78. Airlines operate in a slightly different environment than everyone else, but he did say that he has heard that phraseology, usually on taxi when nearing a runway or takeoff position. He did say that usually, even in busy airports, they still want positive exchange of an aircraft, so a request to monitor doesn't always mean to leave the current channel and wait for the other to contact you. Though if you do hear it, they don't want you talking. ...

Comment: ... I just found it odd, because I have never heard it that way. Even flying to busy Atlanta and a couple of others. Though I will admit to having limited experiences in some of the larger stops in the US.

Comment: FAA  has a specific intent with Monitor.  This is clear when reading FAA ATC Handbook 7110.65, section 2-1-17.      c. In situations where an operational advantage will be gained, and following coordination with the receiving controller, you may instruct aircraft on the ground to monitor the receiving controller's frequency. 

    EXAMPLE-
    "Monitor Tower."
    "Monitor Ground."
    "Monitor Ground Point Seven."
    "Monitor Ground, One Two Zero Point Eight."

Answer (score 4):

To be clear, Cessna N1234, taxi to the ramp, monitor ground point 9, means cleared to the ramp, but listen to ground point 9 for further clearances or for further communication.

You only need to initiate contact, if any is needed.  There is no expectation that you will contact ground (in this example) unless you have a need to.

In contrast, stand by, means wait for further instructions (specifically for ATC to get time to deal with you), and avoid further contact until contacted.

Also, after a clearance, followed by monitor ground point 9, there may never be any further communication.  One just taxi's to the ramp, and when off the controlled portion of the airport, one is free to stop monitoring, and shutdown the radio.

Comment: Mongo, If you get told by ground to monitor tower frequency, when are you allowed to tell the tower that you are ready, to ensure a smooth operation? ( You want to take off without stopping)

Comment: @WalterEVice, any time you have the need.  Normally one will not be told to monitor the tower after a taxi clearance.  But if that were to happen, you can simply call the tower when you have a request. So to answer simply, you are allowed to call at any time, if there is a need.

Comment: Mongo, what is your experience and involvement in aviation? I do agreeing with your answer.

Comment: 44 years as pilot, 37 as CFI-AI, 29 as FAA lead safety rep, corporate test pilot, research scientist in remote sensing and position and time systems, weapons delivery navigation and guidance systems design, other things like seaplane, gliders, towing, etc for fun. 14k hours PIC.

Comment: Thank you Mongo! Do you perhaps have a reference for your answer?Hope to buy you a beer somewhere on our globe!

Comment: It may be in the FAA AIM, but I can also tell you that it is general practice. For example, late at night, when traffic is down, many towers go to reduced staff. One person may be monitoring tower, ground and clearance delivery.  When a call comes in, they answer it.  If they handle someone who just landed, they will tell them after clearing the active to taxi to the ramp and monitor ground. They say that because that way you will hear other ground movements. (You may also hear the tower on the tower, ground and sometimes clearance frequencies.)

Comment: Mongo, I agree with you, however I have a fellow crew member that disagree and the only way to convince him will be with documented proof. I can't find any written evidence and was hoping that someone might help. It seems that common sense is not all that common!

Comment: Here's an article http://atccommunication.com/monitor-the-tower  If you need FAA document, reference ATC handbook 7110.65 section 2-1-17 Radio Communications Transfer:     c. In situations where an operational advantage will be gained, and following coordination with the receiving controller, you may instruct aircraft on the ground to monitor the receiving controller's frequency. 

    EXAMPLE-
    "Monitor Tower."
    "Monitor Ground."
    "Monitor Ground Point Seven."
    "Monitor Ground, One Two Zero Point Eight."